# How to alter a part of an array

Tags: python, arrays, assign

I have an array: `table = [[ 1 for x in range(1, 101)] for x in range(1, 101)]`

Now I want to set some elements to 0. Of course, I could iterate through the table and pick the elements I want to alter, but it doesn't make much sense when I want to alter 25 elements out of 10000. So here is my code:

```
left = randint(1,100)
table[left+1:left+3][left+1:left+3] = [[ 0 for x in range(1,3)] for x in range(1, 3)]
```

However, when I sum all the cells of my array:

```
sum(map(sum, table))
```

I get 10 000.

What is the problem  with this assigment and what is the proper way of doing it?

I'm using Python 2.7 and PyCharm on Windows.

And why does the following line:

```
print len(table[left-1:left+6][upper-1:upper+6])
```

prints out 0?

Comment: FYI, there are no arrays in python. You are talking about lists.

Comment: @ Lafexlos, thanks. But it really doesn't matter. It still doesn't work when I set the part of the list to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have list 100x100,
by this line

```
table[left+1:left+3]
```

You select lists from left+1 to left+3, so the result will be list 2x100.
So, if your variable `left` is greater than 1 this line will try to get lists out of range:

```
table[left+1:left+3][left+1:left+3]
```

result will be probably:

```
[]
```

Example:

```
table = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

so the result of:

```
table[2:4]
```

is

```
[[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

if you try to get range [2:4] from that list you will receive nothing, because it contains only 2 lists:

```
[]
```

/Edit: moved from comment which doesn't support code formatting:

To reply title question. I think quite good solution will be:

```
for row in table[left:left+5]:
    row[right:right+5] = [0 for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's logical:)